# How to check a (unchecked) cast in java?

Tags: java, generics

I have the following problem: I want to write a framework that uses java reflections. I get (from somewhere) the name of a class and I want to load the class and create an instance. As a side constraint all classes that are valid belong to a common superclass.

To keep it simple and easy I do not post all my classes. Instead I coded some sort of "MWE" (see below).

What do I do?
I first define a `String` that simulates the name of the class to be loaded. In my application I get the name from a XML file.
The representing class must be a subclass of a given class (here `File` in my case I have a whole tree of separate classes).
I check if the given name resolves to a class that is a subclass. If it is I should be able to *cast* the `Class<?>` object to a `Class<File>` Object.
Unfortunately eclipse (and therefore `javac`) gives a compile warning.

In this special case it is ok to ignore the warning and I could add an annotation to suppress the warning. All right. But normally there is a cleaner solution to such problems in java. I could also continue to use `Class<?>` and cast later the type when using the object (see in the code for an example).

```
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class ReflectTest extends File
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8807535438772463115L;
    public ReflectTest()
    {
        super("","");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, InstantiationException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException
    {
        String className = "ReflectTest";
        Class<?> clsGen = Class.forName(className);
        if(! File.class.isAssignableFrom(clsGen))
        {
            // Throw some error
            System.exit(1);
        }
        Class<File> cls = (Class<File>) clsGen;
        File f1 = cls.getConstructor().newInstance();
        //Constructor<?> constructor = clsGen.getConstructor();
        //File f2 = (File) constructor.newInstance();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Class.asSubclass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#asSubclass%28java.lang.Class%29):

```
Class<? extends File> cls = clsGen.asSubclass(File.class);
File f1 = cls.getConstructor().newInstance();
```

This is compile-time safe because it will throw `ClassCastException` if `clsGen` isn't really a subclass of `File`.